# How to insert values in .db file using flask?

Tags: python, database, flask

I have folder which contains app.py and books.db file now I want to insert values to that db file using flask.

I am able to read it properly but unable to insert values into it.

Any idea how to achieve this ?

```
@app.route('/insert',methods=['GET','POST'])
def addv():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('books.db')
    conn.row_factory = dict_factory
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute('insert into books values (NULL,2014,\'Vivank\',\'try\',\'trying\')')
    return "inserted"
```

This is not inserting values in books.db ?

Or any way around to insert data into it ?

Comment: What do you mean, achieve _this_ (and then show something that looks like a solution)? What's wrong with it (besides hardcoding strings in SQL)?

Comment: I am unable to insert data in books.db file using python @Amadan

Comment: I mean, what happens when you run the code you posted? Is there an error? Which one? Do you get "inserted" returned or not? Do your curtains burst into flames?

Comment: I got returned but when I view books.db my inserted data is not showing up @Amadan

Comment: Try `conn.commit()`? If the row is updated without an error but not saved, that's probably the only thing missing.

Comment: using `flask-sqlalchemy` is better idea than doing direct insertion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could change your code to something like:

```
@app.route('/insert', methods=['GET','POST'])
def addv():
    if request.method == "POST";
        conn = sqlite3.connect('books.db')
        data = [None, 2014, 'Vivank', 'try', 'trying']
        conn.execute('insert into books values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', (*data,))
        conn.commit()
        return "inserted"
    return "Testing insert"
```